# executeUpdate query not working on grails spock test

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

Now willing to do integration test as below but problem is that

```
MerchantTier.executeUpdate('update MerchantTier..........'),
```

here update does not working

but if I make update with

```
def merchant = MerchantTier.get(params.id.toLong())

merchant.setValue(merchantTierVal)
```

instead of execute update it works

Is there is any prolem with executeUpdate Query?

```
def merchantTier

def setup() {

merchantTier = new MerchantTier(
     startTier: tier,
     endTier: tier,
     value: 2.02).save(flush: true)
}


void "for given merchantTierId update merchantTier"(){

     setup:
     params = [id:merchantTier.id,tierVal:2]

     when:
     testData = updateIndividualSuperResellerTier(params)

     then:"return data"
     merchantTier.value==params.tierVal
}

def updateIndividualSuperResellerTier(params) {

     def merchantTierVal = 0
     if (params.tierVal) {
         merchantTierVal = params.tierVal.toDouble()
     }
     def merchantTier = MerchantTier.get(params.id.toLong())
     def updateMerchantTier = MerchantTier.executeUpdate('update MerchantTier mt set mt.value=:mrValue where mt.id=:mtId', [mrValue: merchantTierVal, mtId: params.id.toLong()])
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this question is really unclear. If you'd anyone to help you, please edit the question and clarify the problem.

Comment: thank you sir, please check the question for given link here question is elaborated and made more clearer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429800/executeupdate-not-update-on-grails-spock-integration-testing

Comment: There's no need to add new question with almost the same content - instead edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem with executeUpdate, the problem here could be, that executeUpdate did not return an object, it just return the number of rows updated so **updateMerchantTier doesnot contain updatedObject**.

Also you should again fetch the object as it is updated by executeUpdate in your **void "for given merchantTierId update merchantTier"()** then: statement

```
then:"return data"
 merchantTier.value==params.tierVal
```

here merchantTier is still an old object hence will not be having value equal to params.tierVal

in your other case you are using setter explicitly to set the property and hence it passed your Integration test.

```
 def merchant = MerchantTier.get(params.id.toLong())
 merchant.setValue(merchantTierVal)
```

hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: thank you Anshul sir, please check the question for given link here question is elaborated and made more clearer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429800/executeupdate-not-update-on-grails-spock-integration-testing