# executeUpdate() not updating on grails spock-integration testing

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing, spock

hi i am new to grails testing. Willing to do integration test as below but 
problem is that `executeUpdate()` seems not updating the value

How to do integration testing for 
`executeUpdate('update query goes here')` ??

Please help suggest me 
Sample code is given for problem demo.
Thanks in advance.

```
def "for given merchantTier Id update merchantTier value"(){
    setup:
    def merchantTier = new MerchantTier(              
            value:1.11).save(flush: true) //it saves merchantTier

    when:"when update with setProperty"
    testData = editWithSetProperty(merchantTier.id) //id is passed

    then:"it updates data and test is success"
    merchantTier.value == 2.22

    when:"executeUpdate query is used instead"
    testData = editWithExecuteUpdate(merchantTier.id)// id is passed

    then:"it does not update the data and test is failed"
    merchantTier.value == 3.33
}

def editWithSetProperty(id) {
    def merchantTier = MerchantTier.get(id.toLong())
    merchantTier.setValue(2.22.toDouble())
}

def editWithExecuteUpdate(id) {
        MerchantTier.executeUpdate('update MerchantTier mt set mt.value=:mrValue where mt.id=:mtId', [mrValue: 3.33.toDouble(), mtId: id.toLong()])
}
```

How to do integration testing for 
`executeUpdate('update query goes here')` ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [executeUpdate query not working on grails spock test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411653/executeupdate-query-not-working-on-grails-spock-test)

Comment: Yes, but that was complex one so i tried to simplify that one.Thank

Answer (score 0):

as you are updating through executeUpdate you again need to fetch the object from database so try returning the fresh object fetched from database in editWithExecuteUpdate

```
def editWithExecuteUpdate(id) {
    MerchantTier.executeUpdate('update MerchantTier mt set mt.value=:mrValue where mt.id=:mtId', [mrValue: 3.33.toDouble(), mtId: id.toLong()])
    merchantTier = MerchantTier.get(id)
}
```

once done then you will have testData containing merchantTier object in when: clause

so in then: clause have

```
 testData.value == 3.33
```

hope this make sense. Thanks

Edit - Additional Way

```
def editWithExecuteUpdate(id) {
    def updatedRecords = MerchantTier.executeUpdate('update MerchantTier mt set mt.value=:mrValue where mt.id=:mtId', [mrValue: 3.33.toDouble(), mtId: id.toLong()])
    return updatedRecords
}
```

so in then: clause have as due to executeUpdate only one row should be updated based on unique id and also fetch fresh object again and check the persisted value

```
 testData == 1
 def freshMerchantTier = MerchantTier.get(merchantTier.id)
 freshMerchantTier.value == 3.33
```

Try this way once, please. Thanks

Comment: Sir, here functional objective is not to return value but check whether data has been persisted or not using exexuteUpdate() , in above case , 
firstly  i  have setup merchantTier  which is gives me object and from that i can access each property like merchantTier.value. Secondly,i have send merchantTier.id in function editWithSetProperty() to edit the content of merchantTier, yet i have not return and it works fine, but when i tried to do same with editWithExecuteUpdate() ,it didnot updated merchantTier.

Comment: Note : executeUpdate('delete query') works fine and have no problem again executeQuery('select query) works fine but problem when update inside excuteUpdate('update') ok if you did not understand above case then you can suggest me how to do testing of executeUpdate(update query) query . Thanks.

Comment: If executeUpdate returns value gt 0, it means data is already persisted for that record, and that you can check easily and also you can check the updated value by fetching the object again.

Comment: Yes i feched merchantTier.get(id).value inside editWithExecuteUpdate() but value was not persisted .What may be the reason ? and how to do testing for function containing executeUpdate('update query here'). Any Suggestion .Thanks

Comment: try hard coding your value and id once in update query and run test. I guess it may not be persisted due to toDouble() and toLong() methods

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have a method that update's an array of object's status attribute from "Open" to "Completed".
My test passes an array of 4 objects, and the return value for the myObject.executeUpdate(...) is 4, indicating that 4 object have been updated,
However, when I fetch the objects again, as @Anshul suggested, their status is still "Open".